# Firebase Firestore only allow user to query a collection if there is a filter

Tags: javascript, firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a Firestore rule which only allows a user to list documents from a collection where they're filtering a field.

```js
// would fail:
db.collection('documents').get();

// would succeed:
db.collection('documents').where('fieldId', '==', 123456).get();
```

Is there a way to accomplish this through Firestore rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with

```
allow list: if int(resource.data.fieldId) > 100000000000000000;
```

since all of the ids are over 100000000000000000. Now attempting to list a collection without .where('fieldId', '==', someId) is rejected.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is with [query based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).

Something like this:

```
allow read: if resource.fieldId.published == 123456;
```

But I don't think there's a way to only require them to filter on `fieldId`, no matter what value.

Interestingly enough, this **is** possible with Realtime Database security rules, which have a separate [clause for `query.orderByChild`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules).

I think this sounds like a reasonable feature though, so I recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). It won't help you now or in any near feature, but... who knows.